# Losing data when rotating screen

Tags: java, android

So I've implemented a `saveInstanceState` method but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong.

What's happening is that when the screen is rotated the question being displayed becomes the first one from the list. But the weird part is that when the question is answered the app is skipping a question and going to the next one.

For example, I'm on question 6. The screen gets rotated, it goes to question 1 again but if I were to answer question 1, the next question that appears is question 8. Each screen rotation is counting as one question. I'm confused.

```
List<Question> mQuestionList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion, times, scored;
Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
private static final String TAG = "NoTimerQuestion";
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private static final String KEY_SCORE = "scoreindex";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this); // my question bank class
    mQuestionList = db.getAllQuestions(); // this will fetch all questions
    currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid); // the current question
    txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
    times.setText("");

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        qid = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX,0);
        score = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SCORE,0);
    }

    setQuestionView();

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button4.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
        score++;
        scored.setText("Score : " + score);
    } 
    if (++qid < 20) {
        currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NoTimerQuestion.this,
                ResultsActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    button4.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, qid);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_SCORE, score);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `qid` when you use it here: `currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid);`?

Comment: Initially the value is 0

Comment: Add a `Log.d()` statement just before this line. You will see that `qid` is `0` **every** time this line executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restore the `qid` before loading the question using `mQuestionList.get(qid)`, otherwise the question will always be the first one as `qid` hasn't been restored yet.

Put it directly after setting the content view, for example (inside `onCreate`):

```
setContentView(/*...*/);
if (savedInstanceState != null){
    qid = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX,0);
}
// Now load your question with the qid
currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid);
```

Also, in order to have the correct `qid` you need to either subtract `1` when restoring the `qid` or only increment it when you're actually loading a new question:

```
public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    // ...
    if (++qid < 20) { // - add increment here
        currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView();
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}

private void setQuestionView() {
    // ...
    // qid++; - remove increment here
}
```

Comment: I tried that before. It's slightly better but still weird. So when I rotate the screen, it still resets to question 1 but it doesnt skip a whole question. Like again if I'm on question 6 and I rotate the screen, it'll show me question 1 and when I answer it it goes to question 7. Does this have something to do with how I update my UI?

Comment: You did mean put that code in front of  "setQuestionView();" right? Or should I put it before the line of code - mQuestionList = db.getAllQuestions(); // this will fetch all questions currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid); // the current question

Comment: No, it should be before the call to `mQuestionList.get(qid)`. You are using `qid` here without having properly restored the question number.

Comment: That's skipping a question. If I'm on question 2 and I rotate the screen it's going to the next question. (Like without me actually picking an answer choice)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: I have one more question, I was trying to implement the same process for score but when the screen rotates, its going to 0 again. I edited my original question to show my attempt at the score code. If you have any tips.

Comment: Updating the `scored` text should do it. Something `scored.setText("Score: " + score)` directly after restoring the score in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `qid` before retrieving its value from the saved `Bundle`. There are many ways to fix this. One solution is to put this line:

```
currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid);
```

at the top of `setQuestionView()`:

```
private void setQuestionView() {
    currentQ = mQuestionList.get(qid);
    //...
}
```

I strongly suggest you learn how to use the debugger in Android Studio or use `Log.d()` in order to trace the execution of your code. These tools will help you track down problems like this.

Comment: When I change the code to that, it's skipping a question. If I'm on question 2 and I rotate the screen it goes to question 3 without me actually picking an answer. And I shall look up the debugger stuff on the developer's page.

Comment: @Sai You are probably changing `qid` before the user answers the question. The only way to find out when this happens is by using some debugging techniques. Good luck!